# undefined method `full_title'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, title

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `full_title'
```

On this line:

```
 <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

On my layouts file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to do something similar to Mike Hartle rails tutorial with the page titles except I am not using tests. So I have not created a support file in the spec folder. I actually have no spec folder. I believe not having the support file with this code:

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

Is causing the error. What is the proper way to fix this is you do not want to create tests and hence don't want a spec folder? Where can I put this code?

Comment: Did you put it in a module and put that module in the helpers directory?

Comment: Do I make the module in my root directory or where? It doesn't say that is my problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any method accessible to the views directly has to go to the helper.

Since you are trying to access this method in your layouts, put your code in the `application_helper.rb` file.

All helpers are modules only.

If you don't have the file, create one in `app/helpers`

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
 end
end
```

Then, `include ApplicationHelper` in application_controller.rb

Comment: I don't have that file, should I create it? If so under what folder?

Comment: all helpers are under the `app/helpers` folder. application_helper is generated by default.

Comment: Thank you! I should have known! Still learning thank you for being so patient this was a thing I had never been able to figure out!