# undefined method `full_title' Hartl Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm learning from the tutorial of mihaela hartla

I know that was similar topic but i the method still does not work
So, I keep getting the the error:

> undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x005594c0761420>:0x005594c0295270>

error in this line **(/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb):**

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

Layouts file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>>
</html>
```

application_controller

```
include ApplicationHelper

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def hello
    render html: "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

application_helper

```
 module ApplicationHelper
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = 'Ruby On Rails Tutorial'

    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
     "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check and try this --> [undefined method `full_title'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630949/undefined-method-full-title)

Can you try commenting or removing

`#include ApplicationHelper`

in your `application_controller` as I am not sure if it is needed there.

Also, is your

`rails -v`

match `5.1.2` or the one in the tutorial

Comment: try cloning and running from my repo as I am working on the same tutorials https://github.com/ragavendra/ragavendra.github.io . Is `application_helper.rb` in `sample_app/app/helpers` directory
May be it is the permissions issue, you may have to have your repo in the user directory like Documents or similar too

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be anything wrong besides the unnecessary inclusion of the ApplicationHelper. Maybe restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the repo you shared with us on Facebook group ([url](https://github.com/Mroczeks/sample_app/tree/rails-flavored-ruby))

The problem there was simple - `application_helper.rb` is empty. In my environment I do not need to include the helper - it works like a charm. Can you please check this and confirm (or update the repo)?